# SQL Count + Left join + Group by ... Missing rows

Tags: mysql

Trying to list all what's in table 1 and records under it in table 2

Table one each row has an id , and each row in table 2 has idontable1

```
select table1.*, count(table2.idintable1)as total
from   table1
       left join table2 on table1.id=table2.idintable1

 WHERE table1.deleted='0' AND table2.deleted=0
group by 
table2.idintable1
```

My current problem is rows from table1 with 0 records in table2 are not displayed
I want them to be displayed

Comment: LEft join with where will transform into an INNER join move the WHERE condition on the JOIN condition `ON x AND y` instead of `ON x WHERE y`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The query that you want is:

```
select t1.*, count(t2.idintable1) as total
from table1 t1 left join
     table2 t2
     on t1.id = t1.idintable1 and t2.deleted = 0
where t1.deleted = 0 
group by t1.id;
```

Here are the changes:

- The condition on `t2.deleted` was moved to the `on` clause.  Otherwise, this turns the outer join into an inner join.
- The condition on `t1.deleted` remains in the `where` clause, because presumably you really do want this as a filter condition.
- The `group by` clause is based on `t1.id`, because `t2.idintable1` will be `NULL` when there are no matches.  Just using `t1.id` is fine, assuming that `id` is unique (or a primary key) in `table1`.
- The table aliases are not strictly necessary, but they make queries easier to write and to read.

Answer (score 1):

You should `GROUP BY table1.id`.

The `LEFT JOIN` ensures all the rows from `table1` appear in the result set. Those that do not have a pair in `table2` will appear with `NULL` in field `table2.idintable1`. Because of that your original `GROUP BY` clause produces a single row for all the rows from `table1` that do not appear in `table2` (instead of one row for each row of `table1`).

Answer (score 0):

You have fallen into mysql's non-standard group by support trap.

Change your group by to list *all* columns of table 1:

```
group by table1.id, table1.name, etc
```

or list the column positions of all table1 columns in the select:

```
group by 1, 2, 3, 4, etc
```

Or use a subquery to get the count vs the id, and join table1 to that.